# Changing class of TD depending if it contains an <a> tag in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Basically I'm fairly new to Javascript/Jquery and am looking for a more full proof way of adding a class to a TD that contains an `<a>` tag.

At the moment 90% of my dataTables contain a final column with  tags in the TD's containing: a Details button, a Delete Button and an Edit button.

So far I have got it working using the following code:

```
$('table.dataTable td:contains("Details")').addClass('tdButton');
```

What bothers me is that there's potential for the final column not to feature the text containing "Details" in the near future. So id rather bind it to the  element.

Here is a brief bit of my html for the TD's:

```
<td class="tdButton">
    <a class="linkButton tdButton" href="/Aptitude2/TestletBank/Details/0da14b39-8fae-e311-9403-00155d0a0c32" id="linkButtonDetails_0">Details</a>
    <a class="linkButton tdButton" href="/Aptitude2/TestletBank/Edit/0da14b39-8fae-e311-9403-00155d0a0c32" id="linkButtonEdit_0">Edit</a>
    <a class="linkButton linkButtonDelete tdButton" href="/Aptitude2/TestletBank/Delete/0da14b39-8fae-e311-9403-00155d0a0c32" id="linkButtonDelete_0">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('table.dataTable td').has("a").addClass('tdButton');
```

or [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('table.dataTable td:has(a)').addClass('tdButton');
```

both selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that using `:has` selector with id selector for anchor tag detail in it:

```
$('table.dataTable td:has(#linkButtonDetails_0)').addClass('tdButton');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cnq4282b/)**

Comment: The asker did not want to rely on having the text "Details"